# Is it possible to use have_posts function to list custom post type posts inside a category?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I'm sure this problem depends on my poor understanding of `categories` and `taxonomies`, but I read a lot around and still can't understand what's going on.

Basically I created a `custom post type` and assigned to it the category taxonomy:

```
function create_post_type()
{
    register_post_type('episode',
        array(
            'labels'      => array(
                'name'          => __('Episodi'),
                'singular_name' => __('Episodio')
            ),
            'public'      => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'taxonomies'  => array('category')
        )
    );
}
```

With this, in the admin panel I'm able to assign my normal categories to it.

Then I created a template for one of these categories, creating a file named `category-my-category.php`.

Inside the file I have this:

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/page', 'header'); ?>
<?php echo single_cat_title(); ?>
<?php if (!have_posts()) : ?>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <?php _e('Sorry, no results were found.', 'sage'); ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php get_template_part('templates/content', get_post_type() != 'post' ? get_post_type() : get_post_format()); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

(By they way, I'm using Roots Sage for this.)
When I click on the category, the template gets loaded correctly, but I couldn't find a way to list my custom posts.

I also tried creating a `taxonomy-my-category.php`, but it doesn't get loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the URL of the page you want to list the "episodi" ?